# No handler found exception and static resources in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a `Spring Boot` web application where I catch my custom exceptions in `ControllerAdvice` class. The problem is that `Spring Boot` doesn't throw exception by default if no handler is found (it sends `json` back to a client).

What I want is to catch `NoHandlerFoundException` in my `ControllerAdvice` class. To make this possible I explicitly configured

```
spring.mvc.throw-exception-if-no-handler-found=true
spring.resources.add-mappings=false
```

This trick does the job and I can catch `NoHandlerFoundException` now but it disables `Spring` to auto-configure path to static resources. So all my static resources are not available for a client now. I tried to resolve this using one more configuration which doesn't help

```
spring.resources.static-locations=classpath:/resources/static/
```

Could anybody please advise how to map static resources in `Spring Boot` when auto-configuration was disabled with `spring.resources.add-mappings=false`?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you found any solution ?

Answer (score 12):

If your static resources are limited to specific URL paths, you can configure only those paths to be handled by the Spring static resources handler. In this example, the `/doc` URL path is served by static resources in the `/resources/static/doc/` folder in the classpath:

```
spring.mvc.static-path-pattern=/doc/**
spring.resources.static-locations=classpath:/resources/static/doc/
```

You'll need to remove this configuration:

```
spring.resources.add-mappings=false
```

Comment: Ok, after some research (and a chat with a Spring developer) I understand this solution better, and it is definitely the way to go. I would just rephrase it to make the two properties clearer (the paths you employ are weird and different from OP's)

Comment: @AndreaRossi I updated the paths to more closely match the OP and added some clarification on the example.

Comment: Breadcrumbs:
With newer Spring Boot versions (>2.4) the property got renamed to `spring.web.resources.add-mappings=false`

Answer (score 3):

I experienced the same issue and after some research, I found out that it is obviously not possible to have both options enabled (i.e. throwing `NoHandlerFoundException` by setting `spring.mvc.throw-exception-if-no-handler-found=true` AND serving static resources automatically).

Enabling the option to throw `NoHandlerFoundException` requires one to set `spring.resources.add-mappings` to `false`, otherwise it would not work. Furthermore, in my test setup it was not possible to disable `spring.resources.add-mappings` and specify the URLs for static resources manually (e.g. via application properties `spring.mvc.static-path-pattern` and `spring.resources.static-locations` or programmatically by overriding `public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry)`), because then the `spring.resources.add-mappings=false` setting seems to be overruled.

Finally, I implemented the following workaround for serving static resources manually via my own controller implementation:

```
@Controller
public class StaticWebContentController {
    
    private Map<String, byte[]> cache = new HashMap<String,byte[]>();

    @RequestMapping(value = "/css/{file}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<byte[]> getCssFile(@PathVariable("file") String name){
        ResponseEntity<byte[]> responseEntity = loadResource(".\\static\\css\\"+name,"text/css");
        return responseEntity;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/img/bootstrap-icons-1.1.0/{file}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<byte[]> getimgFile(@PathVariable("file") String name){
        ResponseEntity<byte[]> responseEntity = loadResource(".\\static\\img\\bootstrap-icons-1.1.0\\"+name,"image/svg+xml");
        return responseEntity;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/js/{file}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<byte[]> getJsFile(@PathVariable("file") String name){
        ResponseEntity<byte[]> responseEntity = loadResource(".\\static\\js\\"+name,"text/javascript");
        return responseEntity;
    }

    private ResponseEntity<byte[]> loadResource(String path, String contentType){
        HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        responseHeaders.add("Content-Type", contentType);
        if(hasCachedContent(path)){
            return new ResponseEntity<byte[]>(getCachedContent(path),responseHeaders,HttpStatus.OK);
        }else{
            Resource resource = new ClassPathResource(path);
            if(resource.exists()){
                try{
                    InputStream inputStream = resource.getInputStream();
                    byte[] content = inputStream.readAllBytes();
                    putCache(path, content);
                    return new ResponseEntity<byte[]>(content,responseHeaders,HttpStatus.OK);
                }catch(IOException e){
                    throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR,e.getMessage());
                }
            }else{
                throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND,"The requested resource '"+path+"' does not exist'");
            }
        }   
    }

    private byte[] getCachedContent(String path){
        return cache.get(path);
    }

    private boolean hasCachedContent(String path){
        return cache.containsKey(path);
    }

    private void putCache(String path, byte[] content){
        cache.put(path, content);
    }

}
```

In my application, I have three types of static resources located in three different sub folders. Each type is handled by a separate endpoint in order to set the `Content-Type` header properly. Moreover, the controller caches each resource in order to avoid to reload the requested resource from hard disk again.

Probably, this is not the best solution, however, a feasible workaround in case of my application. Any recommendations for improvement are highly appreciated!

Comment: Thank you very much for this solution, I had exactly the same issue with the setup described above and I decided to use this approach for serving static files.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of adding below lines to config properties

```
spring.mvc.throw-exception-if-no-handler-found=true
spring.resources.add-mappings=false
```

write your custom Error Attributes as below:

```
@Configuration
public class CustomErrorAttributes extends DefaultErrorAttributes {

    @Bean
    public ErrorAttributes errorAttributes() {

        return new DefaultErrorAttributes() {
            @Override
            public Map<String, Object> getErrorAttributes(RequestAttributes requestAttributes, boolean includeStackTrace) {

                Map<String, Object> errorAttributes = super.getErrorAttributes(requestAttributes, includeStackTrace);
                Map<String, Object> newErrorAttributes = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();
                Object errorMessage = requestAttributes.getAttribute(RequestDispatcher.ERROR_MESSAGE, RequestAttributes.SCOPE_REQUEST);
                if (errorMessage != null) {
                    newErrorAttributes.put("response-type",  "error");
                    newErrorAttributes.put("error-code", errorAttributes.get("status"));
                    newErrorAttributes.put("message",  errorAttributes.get("message"));
                    newErrorAttributes.put("error-message",  errorAttributes.get("error"));
                }
                return newErrorAttributes;
            }

        };
    }
}
```